# computed propert y in vue3 => object is possibly undefined TypeScript,

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

[image]

I already tried using **?** after every word, I already tried something like this:

```
const totalNameLenght = computed(() => {
      if (userFirstnameLenght.value && userLastnameLenght.value){
        return userFirstnameLenght.value + userLastnameLenght.value
    }
  })
```

also tried this one:

```
const totalNameLenght = computed((): number | undefined => )
```

I don't know what else to try... how should I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `userFirstnameLenght` and `useLastnameLenght`? Also, you misspelled "length" (please don't take this to injury, I'm just correcting it if it's a typo). Did you try to use `userFirstnameLenght?.value`? Where do the errors occur?

Comment: Not at all, I appreciate the correction. It's the length from the user first name and last name. I'm passing it via props the user entire Object. I tried to use in the template within a :class={} as a ternary but it was yelling => possible undefined

Comment: you could try `return 0` after the `if` block, that way the computed will ALWAYS return a number

Comment: or `return userFirstnameLenght.value??0 + userLastnameLenght.value??0` and no `if`

Comment: The question asks about the error in general but shows IDE screenshot as a proof. It should be narrowed down on your side. If the app is built and served correctly, the problem is in IDE only, which is very likely. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and doesn't show userFirstnameLenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
    const totalNameLength = computed(() => {
            return Number(userFirstnameLenght?.value ?? 0) + Number(userLastnameLenght?.value ?? 0)
      })
```